# Using Simple Python Parser expression?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

My level is very basic in Python.

This is the python codeblock I have in ArcGIS Field Calculator:

```
def Reclass(THLB):
  if THLB == 0:
    return 0
  elif THLB == 1:
    return !Shape_Area!
```

This works fine if I have another value for elif..say 1. The field populates great. But I can't get the elif to return another field (area in this case).

What am I overlooking?

Both the shape area and field I'm populating are floats.

Comment: Note that the  `!name!` syntax is *not* standard Python. It's some whacko ESRI customization, so don't be surprised if it behaves in remarkably strange ways.

Comment: @jpmc26 the exclamation marks around a field name is definitely not standard python, its a marker used by Esri field calculator to substitute the value of the field *for each feature* and not a string or variable. The confusion arises when one reads about the field calculator syntax and (in my view) the exclamation bounding is not adequately explained; the scope of the variable token !field! is only on one line, the calculation line, and is *out of scope* anywhere else.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Yes, I'm aware. Also, ESRI not explaining something adequately *and* not making it intuitive enough to figure out on your own? Tell me something new. ;) ESRI *must* be preparsing the code snippet and replacing it with some actual Python before evaluating it, and whatever they did doesn't work right except in a very limit scope. How or why they would even do that is beyond me; I should think they would have had to do *extra* work to limit its scope.

Answer (score 3):

!Shape_Area! is out of scope for this calculation, if you want to calculate the values of shape_area you need to specify like this:

```
def Reclass(THLB,Area):
  if THLB == 0:
    return 0
  elif THLB == 1:
    return Area
```

Then call like:

```
Reclass(!Field!,!shape_area!)
```

That is of course provided your data type *has* a shape_area field. If your data is a shapefile or other data source that doesn't have a shape area field you need to [calculate your area first](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s00000027000000).